# AWK double split, trying to keep it on the same line

Tags: bash, file, awk

I am still new to awk but I have an awk command that does 90% of what I want to do. The line I am splitting looks like this.

```
Key1^C{"s":"VALUE"}^BKEY2^C{"s":"VALUE"}^BKEY3^C{"s":"VALUE"}
```

I am splitting it with this awk command

```
awk -F'\02' '{for(x=1; x<=NF; x++) {nf=split($x,f,"\03"); print f[1], "--", f[2], ","}}' inputfile > outputfile.txt
```

It comes out looking like this

```
Key1 -- Value,
Key2 -- Value,
Key3 -- Value,
```

I was hoping someone could help point me in the direction of how to instead if it is possible to have it look something like this

```
Key1 -- Value, Key2 -- Value, Key3 -- Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: (based on your command):

```
awk -F'\02' '{for(x=1; x<=NF; x++) {nf=split($x,f,"\03"); printf "%s",f[1]" -- " f[2] (x==NF?"": ",")}print ""}' inputfile > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: That worked really well in keeping it all on one line, though I have multiple lines that I am reading in. Is it possible to keep all of information from each line on their own line?

Comment: I added a `print ""` at the end, copy the command and try again @TallPaul

Comment: If I run your command @TallPaul, I cannot get your output (the previous multi-lines one). I got 3 lines like `key1 -- {"s":"Value"} ,`

Comment: yeah, I need it parsed but all on one line because I am dealing with a file that is exported from a nosql database so I will never know what columns will be passed in because each line can have different columns and still be in the same table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F'\02' '{for(x=1; x<=NF; x++) {nf=split($x,f,"\03"); tmpvar=tmpvar" "f[1], "--", f[2], ","}}END{sub(/,$/,"",tmpvar); print tmpvar}' inputfile > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[\02\03"]' '{sep="";for(i=1;i<NF;i+=6){printf "%s%s -- %s",sep,$i,$(i+4);sep=", "}}END{print ""}' some.file
```

or, more readable:

```
awk -F'[\02\03"]' '
    {
        sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=6) {
            printf "%s%s -- %s", sep, $i, $(i+4)
            sep = ", "
        }
    }
    END {print ""}
' some.file
```

This uses ^B and ^C and " as field separators. I assume that the JSON snippets after ^C always have both key and value quoted.

Comment: actually yes and no, it looks something like CREATED_TS^C{"s":"2013-08-05T08:29:29.292+0000"}^B. The Key is never quoted but the value always seems to be

Comment: I meant that the values to the left and right of the colon within the braces each will be quoted: `"s"` and `"value"`